# What do `?i` and `?-i` in regex mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

Could someone explain what `(?i)` and `(?-i)` wrapping a word in regex mean?

```
(?i)test(?-i)
```

I tested and it matches `test`, `TEST`, and `teSt`. But I have never seen this before. What does the `?` before `i` mean? I saw this [here](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct/blob/master/lib/carrierwave_direct/uploader.rb#L85).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

`(?i)` starts case-insensitive mode

`(?-i)` turns off case-insensitive mode

More information at the ["Turning Modes On and Off for Only Part of The Regular Expression" section of this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html):

> Modern regex flavors allow you to apply modifiers to only part of the
>   regular expression. If you insert the modifier (?ism) in the middle of
>   the regex, the modifier only applies to the part of the regex to the
>   right of the modifier. You can turn off modes by preceding them with a
>   minus sign. All modes after the minus sign will be turned off. E.g.
>   (?i-sm) turns on case insensitivity, and turns off both single-line
>   mode and multi-line mode.
>
> Not all regex flavors support this. JavaScript and Python apply all
>   mode modifiers to the entire regular expression. They don't support
>   the (?-ismx) syntax, since turning off an option is pointless when
>   mode modifiers apply to the whole regular expressions. All options are
>   off by default.
>
> You can quickly test how the regex flavor you're using handles mode
>   modifiers. The regex (?i)te(?-i)st should match test and TEst, but not
>   teST or TEST.

Comment: Python 3 does support the `(?i)`.

Comment: The selected answer is almost 8 years old today as I write this. The language on the linked to page on regular-expressions.info (my #2 regex site, after regex101) has been CHANGED. I suggest Python users check it out. Similarly, they should consult the updated relevant docs https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.I. Note the docs on re.I for 3.6 are DIFFERENT from the ones for 3.9! Finally, yes, I know this was originally a ruby question, but this answer explicitly refers to Python, so I thought I should warn about updates.

Answer (score 34):

`(?i)` turns on *case-insensitive* mode, `(?-i)` turns it off.

For example, if you tried `(?i)te(?-i)st`, it would match **test**, **TEst**, **tEst**, but not **teST**.

Answer (score 10):

Taken directly from ruby docs.

> The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more
> single-letter options which control how the pattern can match.
>
> /pat/i - Ignore case
>
> /pat/m - Treat a newline as a character matched by .
>
> /pat/x - Ignore whitespace and comments in the pattern
>
> /pat/o -> Perform #{} interpolation only once
>
> i, m, and x can also be applied on
> the subexpression level with the (?on-off) construct, which enables
> options on, and disables options off for the expression enclosed by
> the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you I've never seen the `/i` notation before but I was used to `(?i)` notation.