# SyntaxError in a regex

Tags: javascript

i found a regex that look for matching url here : http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls, the regex is :

```
(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

but when i try to use it in my js file firebug shows me SyntaxError: syntax error exactly in this part `(?i)`

i use the regex like the following :

```
text = $('textarea').val();
url_regex = (?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]));
match = url_regex.exec(text);
```

where is the problem please ?

Comment: Did you copy and paste that line directly into your js, or is there some more code around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145659/what-do-i-and-i-in-regex-mean explains (?i) turns off case sensitivity (?-1) turns case sensitivity back on.

Comment: i update my question, i copy and paste the line without modification, then assign it to url_regex variable

Comment: You need to add delimiters to your pattern. Wrap it in `/` characters to tell Javascript it's a regex.

Comment: Your regex needs to be fenced by `/../` -- see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Comment: @MikeW when i wrap it in / characters firebug shows me error : SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

Comment: @medbo I looked again and there's more to it than that. This is a complex pattern, probably developed fpr PERL, and it might not work in other Regex implementations.

Comment: ok @MikeW thank you :) i search for a regex that can find an url inside a string text, do you know one work good ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, regular expressions are wrapped in `/`s.  Also, the `(?i)` part needs to be replaced with a `i` at the end to make the regex case insensitive.

```
text = $('textarea').val();
url_regex=/\b((?:https?:\/\/|(www\d{0,3}[.])?|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/i
match = url_regex.exec(text);
```

So, as others have said, there are some differences between regex in javascript and perl.

Comment: thank you @SuperScript it works now :) just one question, can i render "www" optional ?

Comment: there is some error in your comment code when i copy past it !! if i understand i need just change this part : (www\d{0,3}[.])? , but it doesn't work without www

Comment: I've edited it into my answer.  Just re-copy the regex there.

Comment: now with this modification it works without www but problem if i put some text before url it doesn't work !! before changes it works even with text first

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression needs to be wrapped in forward slashes and all forward slashes in it needs to be escaped with a back slash.
Second (?i) is a flag to turn on case insensitive mode I guess it's for Perl but not supported in Javascript in the same way.

```
/\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/
```

Should work. Also if you want to turn case insensitive mode you should use like this:

```
new RegExp('.*', 'i');
```