# Validating reference code in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

i need to validate a reference code that is in the form of 2 letters, 3 numbers and one letter. I've tried using for functions, and have also tried going through each letter individually but its either too messy or it's not giving me the result i want. I've heard you can use regex but i'm not sure how to apply it. Any help would be great. Thanks
I was told that this works:

```
reference.matches("[A-z]{2}+[0-9]{3}+[A-z]")
```

but when i run it, no matter what i put into the console that is is incorrect.

Comment: ???? Is it Java *and* Javascript?

Comment: Not that it solves anything but `[A-z]` will match all characters with indexes in Unicode table between indexes of `A` and `z` which means it will also accept `[` ``\`` `]` `^` `_` `\``. Instead you should use `[A-Za-z]` or `[a-z]` with `(?i)` flag which will make your regex case insensitive.

Comment: Anyway [`this tutorial`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) helped me a lot..

Comment: `"AB983X".matches("[A-z]{2}+[0-9]{3}+[A-z]")` gives true for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `that is in the form of 2 letters, 3 numbers and one letter`

You can use this regex:

```
reference.matches("(?i)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}[A-Z]");
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` - for ignore case matching
- `[A-Z]{2}` - for matching 2 letters
- `[0-9]{3}` - for matching 3 digits
- `[A-Z]` for matching single letter

Comment: +1 for using the case-insensitive modifier. A little explanation of it would be helpful - I only just learned about it from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15145701/3150057) =)

Comment: Thanks, added a brief explanation.